# Scrapy crawler not completeing all loops in parse function

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have this code in my crawler

```
class StackSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'stack'
    allowed_domains = ['sitepoint.com']
    start_urls = ["http://www.sitepoint.com"]
    start_page = "http://www.sitepoint.com"
    item = StackItem()

    def init_request(self):

        return Request(url=self.start_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="headline_area"]')
        items = []


        ivar = 1
        for site in sites[:5]:
            item = StackItem()
            log.msg(' LOOP' +str(ivar)+ '', level=log.ERROR)
            item['title'] ="yoo ma"
            request =  Request("http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-to-know-css3-selectors-structural-pseudo-classes/",  callback=self.test1)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            ivar = ivar + 1
            yield request


    def test1(self, response):
        log.msg('  LOOP 2 \n', level=log.ERROR)
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['desc'] = "test4"
        return item
```

I did it as per [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) but it only works on one loop.
I mean i can only see in log on screen

```
LOOP1
LOOP2
```

It should be repeated 3 times

I tried the different combination of return and yield  so

1. `return request`  and `return item` gives output   `LOOP1 LOOP2`
2. `yield request` and `return item` gives output  `LOOP1 LOOP1 LOOP1 LOOP2`
3. `yield request` and `yield item` gives output  `LOOP1 LOOP1 LOOP1 LOOP2`
4. `return request` and `yield item` gives output  `LOOP1 LOOP2`

How can i get `LOOP 1 LOOP2 LOOP1 LOOP2 AND so on`

Comment: Obviously sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="top"]') returns only two items....nobody can proof this since you lack significant information in order to reproduce this any further. Therefore -1

Comment: I can confirm that it has many items from the scrapy shell. thats why i am slicing for teSTING

Comment: What you can confirm does not matter and especially I don't trust in claims without being able to reproduce it myself....

Comment: And once again: fix your indentation!

Comment: i have added the code. which indentation r u talking about

Comment: @user1833746 Try to be a little nicer. It's fine to suggest ways that someone asking a question can improve their question; but try to do so in a helpful, positive tone.

Comment: @Khalid i am puting in pipeline for saving in database. pipline is doing that stuff

Comment: Just to confirm, what version of scrapy are you using and how are you importing InitSpider? So far I've tried to test your code importing from `scrapy.spider` and `scrapy.contrib.spiders` and neither works...

Comment: `from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider` scrapy 0.16

Answer (score 5):

problem is in your loop

```
for site in sites[:5]:
```

you are requesting 1 same URL in loop multiple times.

Scrapy by default filter same requests and ignore them .

if you want to request on same URL multiple times you need to set **`dont_filter=True`**

```
            request = Request("http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-to-know-css3-selectors-structural-pseudo-classes/",
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.test1)
```

then It should be repeated 3 times

Comment: dont_filter was the issue for me. That is the problem for using framework. Too many unknown variables.

Comment: @PraveenSinghYadav its really not a problem not too many unknown variables all you have to do is to check docs
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why your not getting in `Loop 2` is because you have  hardcoded the url in the `Request`. Scrapy dont visit the already visited URL more than once .

Try changing that URL and see how it goes. Don't rely on the order of the message  as  `Requests` don't happen in order